# Have function arguments be keys of static class

Tags: typescript

```
class Example {
    static alpha () {
        return 'a'
    }
    static beta () {
        return 'a'
    }
    static get = <T extends keyof Example> (...keys: T[]) => _.pick(Fragments, keys)
}

Example.get('alpha', 'beta') // {alpha, beta}
```

How can I have a `get` methods that takes key's of Example?

Answer (score 1):

Missing `typeof`

```
class Example {
    static alpha () {
        return 'a'
    }
    static beta () {
        return 'a'
    }
    static get = <T extends keyof typeof Example> (...keys: T[]) => _.pick(Fragments, keys)
}

Example.get('alpha', 'beta') // {alpha, beta}
```